# JQuery css manipulation slows down Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a Problem with CSS manipulation over JQuery. I made a menu that can be dragged in from the left side of the screen and that should just follow the current touch Position wich is retrieved over JQuery mobile (and ist represented by the variable "touch" in the code). At the beginning it works just fine, but when i keep dragging the menu in many times, it becomes very slow and laggy.

Is there any css cache or something that needs to be flushed?

```
menu.css("-webkit-transition", "none");


if (touch.pageX < menu.width()) {

    menu.css("left", (touch.pageX - menu.width()) + "px");
}
```

Sorry that I can't supply a JSFiddle, but it seems that touch events are not supported there.

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the restricted memory space on mobile phones. I can't see all of your code, but maybe you have too many variables, which have to be stored in the memory.

Take a look at your code and search for something like this:

```
Whatever.get("your-selector").doSomething();
Whatever.get("your-selector").doSomething();
Whatever.get("your-selector").doSomething();

var target = $("your-selector");
target.doSomething();
target.doSomething();
target.doSomething();
```

Try to reduce your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I played around with the rest of the code a bit and found out that the problem had nothing to do with the CSS manipulation, but was a result of another function that added hundreds of event listeners.